# How to construct an user-defined counter to generate unique numbers in the mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In a map-reduce program, I want each mapper to generate a unique number (that is different from numbers in other mappers). I think this can be done using a user-defined counter. However, as I understand from counter, the value of a counter is sent to the task tracker when the mapper is done. I got a bit confused how I can generate a unique number in a mapper if that's true.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use  universally unique identifier (UUID) in each of your mapper?

[Please check this link, Java has this inbuilt.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

**Edit after comment:**

If you want the UUID generated only once of all records in a split, you can override the setup method of Mapper class, which is called only once in the beginning of a map task.
The generated UUID can be then stored in a variable to be used for each record in the map() function.

In case you are using the *mapreduce* API, here's how you can do that --

```
public static class SampleMapper extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

   String uuid;

   /**
    * This method will be called once at the beginning
    * of each map task
    */
    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        //generate your uuid here
        uuid = generateUUID();
    }


    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        //use uuid here
    }
```

}

In case of *mapred* API, here's how you can do that --

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> { 

     String uuid;

     @override
     public void configure(JobConf job) {
         uuid = gernerateUUID();
     }

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
              throws IOException { 

          //use uuid here
     }

}
```

[Here is the link.](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html#setup%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context%29)

Comment: If I generate a pseudo-random number using UUID, it changes every time a mapper reads a new record. Am I right? While I want it to stay the same for all the records within a chunk.

Comment: No problem, you can override the setup method in the Mapper class and generate the UUID once and store it in a variable. That should do the trick for you.

Comment: You are using the mapred API or mapreduce API. In mapred API yeah, it's configure().

Comment: Which Hadoop API are you using?

Comment: I generated a random number if the ``configure`` function, but it seems like that there is only one random number shared among all the mappers!

Comment: it seems like the configure function doesn't get executed! I'm using ``hadoop-core-1.1.1.jar`` API

Comment: I'm not talking about the jar you are using, I'm talking about the package and API you are using. So, what do you use to write using mapreduce framework from mappers? context.write() or output collector?

Comment: @Hessam, please check I've updated my answer. Hope that helps!